# AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, pyqt4, executable

Indeed this question is asked many times, but could not find anything to solve my problem. I have many modules in my python project and it works fine, however on creating executable of that project i get error:

> AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'find'

Unfortunately i could not make a reproducible example, as the code is so large. But the error comes from the line, which is to accept user input

```
input = self.builselcom.currentText()
```

which holds something like `hg19.bt2`

I have the index of the above line

```
tofind = ".bt2"
```

and try to find by

```
input.find(tofind)
```

**Note:** Project works fine, but error with executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the user input to string. It should work by just adding `str` to `input = str(self.builselcom.currentText())`. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If that was the problem he would also have it in the development environment (what he calls the 'project').

Comment: You statement seem to be reasonable, I am not sure what version of `Qt` is used, but i guess that executable is not able to `typecast` the user input.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your executable is using a different version of the Qt DLLs.  (I use cx_Freeze and PySide and can only speak for that environment.)  The QString class doesn't exist in the latest DLLs, but it used to; so if this error happened in my setup I would know for sure it was a DLL issue.  Perhaps you can try explicitly copying the DLLs to the executable directory.